# How to return a loop results into a column using a javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Using HTML and bootstrap3, I create one row with 3 column,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="1x"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="2x"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="3x"></p></div>
</div>
```

I want to return results of a loop to each column in this way

```
1        1        1
2        2        2
3        3        3
4        4        4
```

So my code in javascript is

```
var m=1;
var n=1;
  while(m < 4){
    while(n < 4){
        var idname = m + "X";
        var num = toString(n);
        document.getElementById(idname).innerHTML = num;
        n ++;
    };
    m++;
  };
```

However the output I get is

```
4        4        4
```

Can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

HTML,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="1-1"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="1-2"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="1-3"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="2-1"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="2-2"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="2-3"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="3-1"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="3-2"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="3-3"></p></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="4-1"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="4-2"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"> <h3>1x </h3><p id="4-3"></p></div>
</div>
```

JS code,

```
var row=1;
var col=1;
  while(row < 5){
    while(col < 4){
        var idname = row + "-" + col;
        document.getElementById(idname).innerHTML = row;
        col++;
    }

    col = 1;
    row++;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But is there a more effective way. If I need a hundred lines, using your method will need to repeat too many times. Any better way?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solve the problem. My original code

```
...
while(m < 4){
  while(n < 4){
    var idname = m + "X";
    var num = toString(n);
    document.getElementById(idname).innerHTML = num;
...
```

Everytime a new num was generate, the element of the column is replace by a new num, thus the element always be the last num, i.e. 4.
So I change the code into this

```
var m=1;
var n=1;
while(m < 5){
   myarr = [];
   while(n < 5){
      var num = toString(n) + "<br />";
      myarr.push(num);
      n ++;
   };
   var idname = m + "X";
   document.getElementById(idname).innerHTML = myarr;
   m++;
};
```

Now, the outcome is

```
 1        1        1
 ,2       ,2       ,2
 ,3       ,3       ,3
 ,4       ,4       ,4
```

Now the problem is, how can I remove the comma?

Answer (score -1):

You have to put m++ inside the nested loop, or it will not increase at each check.

Comment: this would only iterate over the diagonal